# Библиотека для "рабочих часов" магазина

Tags: php, datetime

Администратор указывает время работы магазина (9:00 - 18:00 местное время, без даты), в БД оно хранится как UTC.

Пользователь передаёт местное время (Y-m-d H:i), необходимо вернуть открыт ли магазин.
Конвертирую UTC в локальное время и пытаюсь сравнить открыт ли магазин. Проблемы начинаются когда магазин, например, открывается в 21:00, закрывается в 03:00.

Возможно есть готовая библиотека или примеры проектов с такой же задачей?

Comment: не проще локальное время переводить в UTC с датой и временем и сравнивать с UTC датой и временем работы магазина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы просто знаем время работы магазина в часах, например 6. Далее указываем время открытия магазина на текущий день, после добавляем время работы "PT6H", получаем время закрытия магазина. Так как все 3 даты объекты `DateTime`, то их можно сравнивать как есть. На выходе проверяем попадает ли дата в текущий промежуток времени. В результате нам не надо определять это следующий или предыдущий день, класс сам сделает данную работу. Далее просто добавьте зону и всё.

**UPD** Дополнил ответ

**UPD2** Ещё дополнил

```
function isOpen($date) {
    $userDate = new \DateTime($date);
    $currentDay = $userDate->format('Y-m-d');
    $openDate = new \DateTime(date("$currentDay 07:00"));
    $open = new \DateTime($openDate->format('Y-m-d H:i'));

    $openDate->add(new \DateInterval('PT6H'));

    $close = new \DateTime($openDate->format('Y-m-d H:i'));
    return ($close->format('H:i') > $open->format('H:i'))
        ? ($userDate >= $open && $userDate < $close)
        : ($close->format('H:i') > $userDate->format('H:i') && $userDate->format('H:i') < $open->format('H:i'));
}

echo isOpen("2021-08-25 06:00");
```

Comment: Спасибо, но echo isOpen("2021-08-25 01:00"); выдаёт false, хотя магазин работает 21:00-03:00

Comment: @geforse дополнил ответ

Comment: @geforse и ещё дополнил раз, чтобы учитывался тот день который запрашивает пользователь

Comment: Если изменить $openDate на new \DateTime(date("$currentDay **07:00**")), то isOpen("2021-08-25 06:00") выдаёт true, хотя магазин открывается в 7 утра

Comment: @geforse обновил ещё раз. Проверяйте =)

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема-то? Тоже мне бином ньютона. Сначала сравнить время открытия и закрытия. Если открывается раньше, чем закрывается (9:00 vs. 18:00), то проверять так. А если открывается позже, чем закрывается (21:00 vs. 3:00), то проверять наоборот.

Comment: Конечно же закрыт! Потому что он откроется только 25 августа в 21:00, а сейчас 25 августа 1:10. До открытия еще почти 20 часов. Вы уже разберитесь, есть у вас даты (как в данном примере) или нет (как в условиях вопроса).

Comment: В условиях написано, что администратор указывает только время работы 21:00-03:00, а пользователь передаёт 2021-25-08 01:00,т.е. магазин в 1час ночи должен быть открыт

Comment: Да. Только в комментарии вы сравниваете не время, а дату/время. У вас по данным в комментарии магазин в час ночи открыт 26 августа. А в час ночи 25 августа - закрыт.

Comment: К сожалению в этом и проблема. Администратор указывает только время работы магазина, а пользователь хочет сделать заказ, например на послезавтра-час ночи и нужно проверить работает ли магазин. Как думаете, как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Я уже написал как решить. Нужно сравнивать **время**. А **дату** не принимать во внимание. 2021-08-25 21:00 раньше, чем 2021-08-26 03:00, но 21:00 позже, чем 3:00 и поэтому результат сравнения противоположный.